# zoom by dragging a box in gxp geoexplorer suite

Tags: boundless-suite, geoexplorer

How to add zoom by dragging a box in gxp opengeo suite?

I need to add the tool box zoom by dragging the mouse

---

mm yes, but in gxp do not exist

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This button already exists on the default toolbar:

[image]